# How To query database and find equality between Rows regardless of String abbreviation

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query address database using specific value I had, the value that I hold may contain abbreviation such as 212 East AVE, and the rows in database may had this street address by AVENUE instead of AVE, and their are more abbreviation am aware of but need to know how to handle this query

Comment: You could look up each entry on an external map data service (e.g. google maps or something), and let them correct the address for you, "normalize" it if you want. Then, save the "normalized" address in your database

Comment: so I can use google map to normalize the addresses? is it free service?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a bunch of regexp_replace functions, but the code gets ugly fast; the following is simplistic handling of Ave to AVENUE and Rd to ROAD, but it is probably not completely correct:

```
select 
  regexp_replace( 
    regexp_replace( 
      regexp_replace( 
        regexp_replace( 
          regexp_replace( 
              regexp_replace( 
                regexp_replace(STREET_ADDRESS, 'Str$', 'STREET', 1, 0, 'i')
              , 'St$', 'STREET', 1, 0, 'i')     
            , 'Street', 'STREET', 1, 0, 'i')     
          , 'Ave[.]?$', 'AVENUE', 1, 0, 'i')  -- Handle "Ave." or "Ave" at end of line
        , 'Ave[.]? ', 'AVENUE ', 1, 0, 'i')  -- Handle "Ave Apt 314", "Ave. Apt 314"
      , 'Avenue[ ]?', 'AVENUE ', 1, 0, 'i')  -- Handle "Avenue", "Avenue Apt 314"
    , ' Rd', ' ROAD', 1, 0, 'i') -- Handle " Rd" but ignore "Oxford" 
  as fixed_address
from location;
```

But this would be a nightmare, the United States Postal Service has a list of [official suffixes](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm) for street names, and there are 206 official suffixes and 502 commonly used suffixes.  For example, For "Alley" the official abbreviation is `ALY` but common are `ALLEY`, `ALLEE`, `ALLY`, and `ALY`!

I played with an extension of the Oracle sample HR schema `location` table to test the above query and you can see the results of the [SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3cd51/7).

Probably the best approach would be to write a PL/SQL function (to ease maintenance when someone comes up with an interesting new way to abbreviate "Alley") to translate a user's query into the (hopefully) standardized data in your database table.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to guess every way a street suffix could possibly be abbreviated, it might be more useful for you to do an approximate search.  Since street suffix abbreviations do always start with the same letter as the street suffix, you can use the first letter of the street suffix, followed by % (the % symbol means "match any").

For example, if the table has:

```
 ADDRESS
 -------
 212 East Ave
 514 West Avenue
 212 3rd St
 212 East Alley
```

You can run this query:

```
 Select ADDRESS from TABLE_1 
 where ADDRESS like '212 East A%'
```

and it will give this result:

```
 ADDRESS
 -------
 212 East Ave
 212 East Alley
```

So, by doing an approximate search, you will get your result, though in rare cases you may also get a few extra results if the number and street name match exactly (though this will probably happen rarely).